# Heap Corruption using cv::FlannBasedMatcher and std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, feature-extraction, heap-corruption

I am developing a breast imaging features for object recognition, using FlannBasedMatcher to compute spatial histograms.

```
Mat ComputeSpatialHistogram(Mat features, Mat vocabulary, int* region_index, int level, Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> flann_matcher)
{
   int vocab_size = vocabulary.rows;
   Mat descriptor = Mat::zeros(1, vocab_size*my_pow(4, level), CV_32FC1);
   if (features.rows > 0)
   {
        vector<DMatch> matches;
        flann_matcher->match(features, matches);
        int word_idx, region_idx, descr_idx;
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++){
            word_idx = matches[i].trainIdx;
            region_idx = region_index[i];
            descr_idx = vocab_size*region_idx + word_idx;
            descriptor.at<float>(0, descr_idx) = descriptor.at<float>(0, descr_idx) + 1.0f;
        }
    }
    return descriptor;
}
```

I get an error when ending the execution of the if(features.rows > 0) scope. Can you helpme?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Your code does no check if region_index[i] is a valid array entry.  You're using `i` to refer to two differing things, one is a vector, and the other is a pointer to a buffer which we do not know the size of.  That function should take either a size for the maximum number of region_index values, or rewritten to use a std::vector<int> for the region_index.  Either case, the loop has to be rewritten so that you don't fall over the edge and start indexing invalid region_index entries.  If making this change solves the issue, I will make it an answer.  RIght now it is a comment on the coding done.

Comment: I get a heap corruption error.

Comment: @jperezmartin `I get a heap corruption error` Writing beyond the bounds of an array can corrupt the heap.  These are the faults I see in the code that you posted, and I don't even know `cv`.

Comment: The size of region_index and matches is equal to features.cols, it isn't the problem.

Comment: This code compiled with Visual Studio 2013 does not produce any error, the error occurs when compiled with visual studio 2010

Comment: @jperezmartin `The size of region_index and matches is equal to features.cols,`  If I had a dollar for every time someone says "it works without me proving it, trust me", I would be a rich man.   In addition to what I stated earlier, we have no idea if that pointer is pointing to valid memory or not.  Remember that you are getting a crash, and that can be caused by all of the things I mentioned.

Comment: The size of region_index and matches is equal to features.rows, it isn't the problem. And this code compiled with Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCV 2.9 does not produce any error, the error occurs when compiled with visual studio 2010 and OpenCV 2.2

Comment: Mentioning that it works with compiler "A" and doesn't for compiler "B" means nothing in the world of C++.  There could still be a bug in the code that seemingly works.  C++ has something called *undefined behavior" which doesn't exist in most other languages.  Until there is bonafide proof it is a compiler or CV issue, then it is a bug in your code that doesn't manifest itself in VS 2013 in a way that can be seen visibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting

```
matches.reserve(size)
```

with the actually size of the vector, before insert any element. This is necessary if you're using the OpenCV 2.2, but not with the 2.9